# Binding List of KeyValuePairs in DataGrid, each key is coulmn header

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, keyvaluepair

I have an object with specified parameters (strings/ints) and `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`

```
 public class Product
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ReferenceNumber { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> AttributeList { get; set; }
}
```

I want to bind this object to DataGrid, but I want to have each record in KVP as Column header and value. Such like:

```
AttributeList  = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
   new KeyValuePair{"SIZE", "30"}, new KeyValuePair{"WIDTH", "50"}
}
```

AttributeList keys are static in API different to category. At the one time I can have only one list of keys.
I don't have idea how to bind that.

Comment: What's your XAML like ? You may need to use ValueConverter (https://www.wpftutorial.net/valueconverters.html)

Comment: @auburg I'm using AutoGenerateColumns

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197738/set-autogeneratecolumns-true-and-auto-convert-by-the-datatype

Answer (score 0):

You need a pivot table.  The code below create a DataTable that is equivalent to a excel pivot table that you can bind to.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

            List<string> keys = products.Select(x => x.AttributeList.Select(y => y.Key)).SelectMany(x => x).Distinct().ToList();

            DataTable pivot = new DataTable();
            pivot.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(long));
            pivot.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            pivot.Columns.Add("ReferenceNumber", typeof(string));
            pivot.Columns.Add("Category", typeof(string));
            foreach (string key in keys)
            {
                pivot.Columns.Add(key, typeof(string));
            }

            foreach (Product product in products)
            {
                DataRow row = pivot.Rows.Add();
                row["Id"] = product.Id;
                row["Name"] = product.Name;
                row["ReferenceNumber"] = product.ReferenceNumber;
                row["Category"] = product.Category;
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> attr in product.AttributeList)
                {
                    row[attr.Key] = attr.Value;
                }

            }

        }
    }
    public class Product
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ReferenceNumber { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> AttributeList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it be shorter to use SelectMany as the very first method: `products.SelectMany(x => x.AttributeList.Select(y => y.Key)).Distinct()`?

Comment: @ASh : Yes your correct.   I'm just use to putting the SelectMany at the end of the query.  Usually I using a GroupBy and then SelectMany.